# Temporary brace for a wooden retaining wall

Tags: retaining-wall

I have a 2.5 ft tall retaining wall made with 2x6 planks held up by 4x4 wooden posts.
Part of the retaining wall is now blowing out after the Texas winter power outage.
I believe that my pool behind the retaining wall has a cracked pipe somewhere.

While I wait for insurance and contractors, I need a way to temporarily hold the retaining wall up.
I think some 2x4s braced against the ground would be fine enough, but Im not entirely sure how to make sure that the 2x4s themselves dont push out from the wall.

Does anyone have an image or drawing of how a **temporary** brace would look like?

I have searched online, but I have only found braces that you can buy for concrete walls in larger construction projects.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Nail 2x4 or 2x6 horizontal near top or middle of wall for a stop.  Will need to use something to stop 2x4 from sinking into ground. Like broken cement block dug into ground.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to purchase special braces, just use some common lumber.

When i set fence posts I use a 2"x 4" and wood stake.

Lay your 2x4 on your wall at angle, the farther the end that will be at  the ground/stake is away from the wall the more lateral stability you will have. Secure the brace to the wall, you may need to add some scrap wood to attach it to, another 4 foot 2x4 screwed to the wall vertically will give you a good attachment point.

With brace in place set your stake at the end of the brace right up against the side   and use a heavy hammer to drive in the ground solid. Now you can screw the brace to the stake. It is best to pilot drill the stake so the screw does not split it.

[Tutorial for setting fence posts](https://www.outdooressentialproducts.com/en/Projects/How-to-Dig-Post-Holes-and-Set-Fence-Posts)

Photo from link.

[image]

I have No affiliation with Outdooressencialproducts . com

Answer (score 0):

Look at how they support walls for foundation works.

Plates to spread load at both ends and sufficient beams to achieve the goal - usually all at angles as they are hammered into position.

Cut to length as needed and some end up with spacer blocks as it all moves.